# swig 3.0.10 Examples/python/callback can the callback function return a tuple?

Tags: python, callback, swig

The notion here is to just extend the example to have the "run()" member function return a tuple of two values. I have been looking far and wide and haven't found that this is possible. The example includes this function with no return values:

```
virtual void run() { 
    std::cout << "Callback::run()" << std::endl; }
```

I have been able to get this to work:

```
virtual long run() { 
    std::cout << "Callback::run()" << std::endl; return 23; }
```

I have been able to get this to work:

```
virtual long run(long value) { 
    std::cout << "Callback::run()" << std::endl; return 23+value; }
```

But the typical "append the output" feature does not appear to work with the director/callback mechanism:

```
virtual long run(long *rcP) { 
    std::cout << "Callback::run()" << std::endl; *rcP = 99 ; return 23+value; }
```

Where the following SWIG directive in "example.I":

```
%include typemaps.i
%apply long *OUTPUT { long *rcP };
```

would normally cause the function to return a tuple of "(23+value, 99)".

I have not found a combination of SWIG directives that will generate a tuple on the callback; but in the case of the director/callback there is no linkage created between the argument and the return value at all.